# Fibonacci Recursion Value tracer

Tags: matlab, fibonacci, persistent

So I need to write a program which uses a recursive function to store the value of input arguments in the order they were made.

e.g. If my function is `[f trace]=fibo_trace(6,[])` it should return

```
[f trace]=fibo_trace(6,[])
f=
    8
trace=
    6     4     2     3     1     2     5     3     1     2     4     2     3     1     2
```

With `trace` being the values with which the recursive call is being initialized and `f` being the 6th element in the fibonacci series.

Here is my code

```
function [f,trace] = fibo_trace(n,v)
    
    persistent ptrace;   % must specify persistent
   
    v=n; 
    ptrace=cat(2,ptrace,v);
   
    
    if n <= 2
        f = 1;
    else
        f = fibo_trace(n-2) + fibo_trace(n-1);
    end
    trace=ptrace;
end
```

But using a persistent variable does not give proper output if multiple conditions are tested. I need to compute this without using a persistent or global variable, can anyone help me out here?

When I don't use a persistent variable only the latest value of `n` is stored in vector `v` instead of the entire set of values.

Answer (score 2):

First, note that your input `v` is never used, you always overwrite it with `n`.

Next, note that your calls to `fibo_trace(n-1)` and `(n-2)` could return `trace`, you're just choosing not to. We can take advantage of the 2nd output to build the `trace` array.

These two points mean you can get rid of the persistent variable, and simplify the code a bit. We just need to make separate calls to `fibo_trace` for the two previous iterations.

```
function [f,trace] = fibo_trace(n)     
    if n <= 2
        % The trace should just be 'n' for the starting elements f=1
        f = 1;
        trace = n;
    else
        % Get previous values and their traces
        [f1, t1] = fibo_trace(n-1);
        [f2, t2] = fibo_trace(n-2);
        % Compute the outputs
        f = f1 + f2;
        trace = [n, t2, t1];
    end
end
```

Result:

```
[f, trace] = fibo_trace(6)
f =
     8
trace =
     6     4     2     3     1     2     5     3     1     2     4     2     3     1     2
```

There's some optimisation to be had here, since `fibo_trace(n-1)` will itself call `fibo_trace(n-1)`, so computing `fibo_trace(n-2)` separately is multiplying the computation time.