# I have to write a function that recursively determine the recursive calls of fibonacci series

Tags: matlab

I have written the following code but not getting the correct the value of x. However we I remove semicolon from line2 it seems as if I am getting correct answer. But output doesn't come correct.

```
function [f, x]=fibo_trace(n,sak)
      trace=tracker(n)
      x=trace;
    if n<=2
        f=1;   
    else
        f=fibo_trace(n-2)+fibo_trace(n-1);
    end
end
function sak=tracker(n)
    persistent i;
    persistent k;
    if isempty(i) || isempty(k)
        i=1;
        k=[];
    end
    k(i)=n;
    sak=k;
    i=i+1;
end
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fibonacci Recursion Value tracer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63555236/fibonacci-recursion-value-tracer)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you like to track, but I suggest that you always pass and return the x.

If you like to trace the calculated inputs (n) of the recursic function, you could code something like this:

```
function [f, x]=fibo_trace(n)
    i = 0;
    x = [];
    [f, x] = fibo_trace_rec(n, x);
    function [f, x] = fibo_trace_rec(n, x)
        i=i+1;
        x(i) = n;
        if n<=2
            f = 1;
        else
            [f2, x] = fibo_trace_rec(n-1, x);
            [f1, x] = fibo_trace_rec(n-2, x);
            f = f1+f2;
        end
    end
end
```

Result then is:

```
>> [f x] = fibo_trace(6)    
f =    
     8        
x =    
     6     5     4     3     2     1     2     3     2     1     4     3     2     1     2
```

Or if you instead like to have the fibonacci sequence in x, e.g. like this:

```
function [f, x]=fibo_trace(n)
    x = [];
    [f, x] = fibo_trace_rec(n, x);
    function [f, x] = fibo_trace_rec(n, x)
    if n<=2
        f = 1;  
        x(1) = 1; % set x for n == 1 because, for n==2, n==1 is never called!
    else
        [f2, x] = fibo_trace_rec(n-1, x);
        [f1, x] = fibo_trace_rec(n-2, x);
        f = f1+f2;
    end
    x(n) = f;
    end
end
```

Result then is:

```
>> [f x] = fibo_trace(6)    
f =    
     8        
x =    
     1     1     2     3     5     8
```

Comment: I have to admit, the solution in "Fibonacci Recursion Value tracer" suggested by obchardon is even cleaner.